# Using the inverse Gaussian integral to find percentiles

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I need some help with the following:

Let $$R=\mu+\sigma*\epsilon \hspace{1cm} \epsilon \sim N(0,1)$$

I want to argue that $$ \mu + \sigma*\Phi^{-1}(u)$$
are the percentiles of the model when $\Phi^{-1}(u)$ is the inverse Gaussial integral.

How can I do that?

Thanx!

Comment: More often written $\Phi^{-1}$ rather than $\theta^{-1}$.

Comment: Thanx. Changed it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not totally obvious to me what you are asking for, but I would have thought the argument is something like

$$\Pr(R \le \mu + \sigma \Phi^{-1}(u)) = \Pr(\epsilon \le  \Phi^{-1}(u)) = \Phi(\Phi^{-1}(u)) =u$$

Comment: Do one have to demand of $\Phi$ to be strictly increasing for the last part to work?

Comment: $\Phi$ is a cumulative distribution function so is increasing. Its derivative (the density) is positive on the whole real line, so it is continuous and strictly increasing. So it has an inverse.